# How to ignore "Content-Disposition: attachment" in Firefox

Tags: http, firefox, browser, download

How can I cause Firefox to **ignore** the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header?
I find it absolutely annoying that I can't view an image in the browser, because it asks me to download it.

I don't want to download the file, I just want to view it in the browser. If the browser doesn't have a plugin to handle it, **then** it should ask to download.

E.g. I have Adobe Acrobat Reader installed as a plugin for Firefox. I click a link to a PDF, and it asks me to save it, when it should open in the browser using the plugin. This is the behaviour if the server does not send the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header in the response.

Firefox 3.6.6
Windows XP SP3

Comment: What's so wrong with selecting "Open With: Acrobat Reader" and getting an Acrobat Reader window?  This will only save the file to your temporary dir, same as if you'd opened it in the browser.

Comment: Simply, it just uses too many windows. See below.

Comment: @Borealid I remember pdfplugin used to display the file as it's being fetched (without having to fetch it all/download it first then displaying it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ["Open in browser" extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8207/) is useful for formats supported natively by the browser, not sure about PDF.

Legacy version 1.18 (for users of browsers such as Waterfox Classic) is in the [Classic Add-ons Archive](https://github.com/JustOff/ca-archive/) at:

- caa:addon/open-in-browser

Comment: I already found this extension before you answered, but that's what i finally did.

Comment: Just tried installing the extension, and it asks for permission to access browsing history and other things it should not need.  That maybe the author's carelessness, or an attempt to make money off of the user's private data. In the latter case, we need an alternative...

Comment: You can check the [source code](https://github.com/Rob--W/open-in-browser/blame/master/extension/manifest.json) to see why certain permissions are needed -- a quick search indicates it uses it only to [remove](https://github.com/Rob--W/open-in-browser/commit/8c423c12a70f2870150174ee51cf5ecef1945f6e) its own entries from the [history](https://github.com/Rob--W/open-in-browser/commit/91b9d8c23c7171c6937732860d7b2738c6dcee65). Though I didn't review it thoroughly, I feel your concerns are unfounded - it looks like a problem with the extensions system, not with the particular extension.

Answer (score 12):

Legacy [InlineDisposition](https://web.archive.org/web/20171102053701/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/inlinedisposition/) 1.0.2.4 by Kai Liu can fix this problem.

In the [Classic Add-ons Archive](https://github.com/JustOff/ca-archive/) at:

- caa:addon/inlinedisposition

Comment: This is the solution to avoid those popups asking you to save or open the file, with the "don't ask this question" box ticked (even though it's asking you the question it claims it won't ask.)  It works by changing the Content-Disposition header so you get the behaviour you want from the browser, namely respecting your choice that you always want a particular action to be performed without being asked.

Comment: This is a cleaner solution that avoids the pop-up.  Here's a newer version of it compatible with Firefox Quantum:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/inlinedisposition-reloaded

Answer (score 1):

I also [found this](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-49707.html) tonight that totally prevents Firefox from littering your desktop with downloads. It's actually a redirect fix to the hidden /private/temp folder in MAC. Genius.

> You can mimic the Windows behaviour simply by changing [Firefox's]
>   download directory to `/tmp`.
>
> To do this, open `Firefox's General preferences` pane, under `Save
>   Downloaded Files To` select [choose].... In the dialog that appears,
>   hit `Shift-Command-G` to bring up the `Go to Folder` dialog.
>
> In this dialog, simply type `/tmp`, hit `OK`, then hit `Select` in the
>   main window.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's the purpose of disposition type "attachment".

The default behavior (when the header is absent) should be to display in-line.

Maybe there's a configuration problem in your browser, or the Reader plugin?

Comment: Nah, images are handled by Firefox directly; without a plugin. What I'm saying is I don't want to download it, I just want to see it.

The biggest reason for this is to prevent excess windows from opening.
Normally, I click a link, see the file. But in some cases (like download this image) open a new window "Your download will begin shortly" which opens a Firefox dialog (Yes, I know I can skip this) so I choose "open with", the file downloads, then the program opens. Count these up. That's 5 windows for what in all other cases is 1.

Comment: Again: check that your reader plugin is configured properly (try another machine?). Check the HTTP Trace (is the header really present). Optimally, supply a test case that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The *site* is adding the header to say *it* wants you to download it. It's perfectly reasonable to want the browser to let you override this (just like it does for thousands of other actions: open in new tab, block javascript, etc etc).

Answer (score 0):

For PDFs there is an addon called [PDF-Download](http://www.pdfdownload.org/) which overrides any attempt to download a PDF and lets the user decide how they want it downloaded (inline, save, external, etc).  You could probably modify it to work for other filetypes too.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was looking for a solution and no available add-on was actually working with my Firefox 31.0 (Ubuntu) I decided to try creating my own add-on.

The code if you want to archive a similar goal or just want to know how it works.

```
console.log("starting addon to disable content-disposition...");

//getting necessary objects
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");

//creating the observer object which alters the Content-Disposition header to inline
var httpResponseObserver = {
    //gets fired whenever a response is getting processed
    observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
        if (topic == "http-on-examine-response") {
            var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
            httpChannel.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline", false);
        }
    }, 
    //needed for this.observerServer.addObserver --> without addObserver will fail
    get observerService() {
        return Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
    },
    //used to register with an observer
    register: function() {
        console.log("register with an observer to get response-events");
        this.observerService.addObserver(this, "http-on-examine-response", false);
    },
    //used to unregister from the observer
    unregister: function() {
        console.log("unregister from observer");
        this.observerService.removeObserver(this, "http-on-examine-response");
    }
};

//gets called at enable or install of the add-on
exports.main = function(options, callbacks) {
    console.log("content-dispostion main method got invoked");
    //call register to make httpResponseObserver.observe get fired whenever a response gets processed
    httpResponseObserver.register();
};

//gets called on disable or uninstall
exports.onUnload = function(reason) {
    console.log("content-dispostion unloaded");
    //unregister from observer
    httpResponseObserver.unregister();
};

/*

//not needed!!! just test code for altering http-request header

var httpRequestObserver =
{
  observe: function(subject, topic, data)
  {
    console.log("in observe...");
    console.log("topic is: " + topic);
    if (topic == "http-on-modify-request") {
      var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
      httpChannel.setRequestHeader("X-Hello", "World", false);
    }
  },

  get observerService() {
    return Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
  },

  register: function()
  {
    this.observerService.addObserver(this, "http-on-modify-request", false);
  },

  unregister: function()
  {
    this.observerService.removeObserver(this, "http-on-modify-request");
  }
};
httpRequestObserver.register();
*/
```

As an alternative you can get my xpi-File to directly install the add-on in Firefox. If you want to disable the "Content-Disposition" altering just deactivate the add-on ;-).

http://www.file-upload.net/download-9374691/content-disposition_remover.xpi.html

Answer (score -1):

You could write a firefox extension that removes the disposition header for PDF files.  This would be a fairly simple extension.