# SSRS 2012 Remove Content-Disposition in Response Headers

Tags: reporting-services, httpresponse, ssrs-2008-r2, response-headers

Is there a way to make SQL Reporing Services not adding *`Content-Disposition: attachment;`* inside response headers.
In my app I call SSRS over url with param `rs:Format=PDF`
That Param push SQL Reporting Services to instantly deliver PDF file with generated report to user.
To save users  two or three clicks I'll love to try open that PDF directly inside Chrome or FireFox.
I manage to remove these Headers at client side inside [Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251575/how-to-ignore-content-disposition-attachment-in-firefox) and [Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/199382/make-chrome-always-open-pdfs-itself).
What I want to try is to hack reporting services not to sending these headers at all.
So users do not have to instal extra extensions inside browsers.

Comment: How are you making the call to SSRS? Is there code-behind or is it just a link to the report?

Comment: To remove it, you probably need some server-side code that makes the SSRS request behind the scenes, strips out the header, and returns the modified content to the user.